# How to echo js code from file

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to make small "api" about including banners.. so i have 1 php file with content like that:

```
echo'
  <a href="https://yaskidki.ru/referer/'.$_GET[referer].'" target="blank"/>
    <div id="yaimg"></div>
  </a>

  <script>
  function yaGetImg(size)
  {
    if(size=="400x100")
    {
      var el = document.getElementById("yaimg");
      el.innerHTML="<img src=\"https://yaskidki.ru/rek/yabimg400x100.gif\" width=\"400px\" height=\"100px\">";
    }
  }
  </script>
  ';
```

i would like to GET contnet of this file by inserting code like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://yaskidki.ru/rek/referer/vljskrnh66"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">document.write(yaGetImg("400x100"));</script>
```

In my example nothing works.. Can some one tell me how it must be correct?

Comment: Use $_GET['referer']. Missing qoutes.

Comment: You cannot able to use PHP like this, for setting any kind of html or javascript

Comment: `yaGetImg` don't return anything so `document.write` will not print anything.

Comment: And you can't have html inside javascript file.

Comment: @Kirankumar What way will be right to make what i want? My task is to insert image with special link (for any domain or web page)

Comment: from where you are getting this image, means from database or xml file etc ?

Comment: it's just on folder on server..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use php file in script tag you need to echo javascript not html, try:

```
echo 'function yaGetImg(size)
  {
    if(size=="400x100")
    {
      var str = "<a href=\"https://yaskidki.ru/referer/'.$_GET['referer'].'\" target=\"blank\"/>' +
                "<div id=\"yaimg\"><img src=\"https://yaskidki.ru/rek/yabimg400x100.gif\" width=\"400px\" height=\"100px\"></div>'+
                "</a>";
      return str;
    }
  }';
```

then you will be able to use this function as `document.write(yaGetImg("400x100"));` because document.write expect string.

Answer (score 2):

It's imposible. PHP is the server side engine and it's rendering all html content and sending it to the browser.
Then client side (browser) loads JavaScript scripts.

Comment: so how i can modify it? i need insert banner with link from any domain or page on site